# Is there a way to shift text from the middle of a cell to the start of the cell in google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, text, replace, spreadsheet

I'm working on a spreadsheet of movies and I need to find all instances where a cell in a specific column is of the form "*, The (year)" and replace it with "The, * (year)". For example, a cell with the text "Sound of Music, The (1965)" should become "The Sound of Music (1965)", and the same for the rest of the entries in the column with the same problem.

Comment: to avoid downvote or closing you should be more specific in including what exactly you have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regular expression `(.*), (The )(\(\d+\))` replacement `$2$1$3`

match your input into regex groups enclosed in parentheses. Escape literal parentheses with backslash. replace by referring the matched group with $ sign and index.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JtntBbKSCoT3VkAU)